# How to burn an iso while downloading it

Tags: system-installation, wget, usb-drive, download, burning

I'm in a real hurry so I thought there is a way to do that but I don't know how.
I thought about piping `wget -c cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/utopic-desktop-amd64.iso | BurningApp` but I don't know how either.

I usually use Unetbootin to "burn" it to a USB Flash Storage Device.Currently I'm running Lubuntu 14.04/10.

Please note I want to burn it to a USB Flash Storage Device.

Comment: I wonder if it's really possible. At least, you would have to give to the burner some extra information, like the total size of the `.iso` file, before it can start burning.

Comment: @lgeorget: Why would it need that? Back in the day it used to be the way to go to `mkisofs ... | cdrecord ...`. If that information is really required it's probably in the meta information of the iso-image. I have forgotten most of it, but appart from buffer underrun problems, which also should be a thing of the past, I do not see why `wget -O - http://path.to/image.iso | cdrecord ...` should not work. I'm just not posting an answer because I don't recall which parameters `cdrecord` needs, let alone what's sensible for the problem at hand.

Comment: @Bananguin @ Igeorget Please note I want to burn it to a USB Flash Storage Device

Comment: @NatusVincere: Could you please elaborate on the process of burning onto USB flash disks? I am not familiar with this. What does it accomplish?

Comment: if you want to transfer the iso (as is) without partitioning the usb drive you can use dd to acomplish that. Have in mind that you will loose space from the usb since you are not partitioning it and the only partition after the process will be the one contained in the iso.

Comment: @Bananguin It will not work, because `|` character means that stadard output is piped to another program. Since wget doesn't print content of downloaded files, the burning program will not receive `.iso` file.

Comment: @Fiodor: I'll have to disagree, I'm afraid. The man page for `wget` states quite unambiguously in the section on the `-O` option "If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output"

Comment: @Bananguin Ok, thank you for the information, I used to use cdrecord and it always checked the size of the media as well as the soundness of the commandline options before burning, so I don't know how it manages a stream input. For a USB device, I guess it would be sufficient to do `wget -c cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/utopic-desktop-amd64.iso -O - | dd of=/dev/sdX` where `/dev/sdX` is the USB device. Could you try @NatusVincere?

Comment: @lgeorget: If that's what burning onto a flash drive is ...

Comment: @Bananguin Well... in a perfect world, `dd` would also work correctly on CDs. We call writing to a disk "burning" because of the physical operation that takes place but it would actually be nice if a CD filesystem would have the same interface than any other FS (and handle all the usual syscalls smoothly). On USB devices, the operation is simpler and doesn't require special software. Plain old `dd` will do.

Comment: @lgeorget: "burning" in the sense of "heating significantly beyond friction with the intention to store data" happens only with discs, not disks, and definetly not flash drives. Yet we still don't know if the OP wants the ISO written to the flash drive or a partition on the same ...

Comment: @Bananguin "disc" with a "c" indeed. I guess the objective is to obtain a bootable USB device, so no partition. Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: @lgeorget: you could bei right. The op wont explain

Answer (score 5):

Example using `wget` (for downloading), `bfr` (for buffering), and `growisofs` for burning:

```
wget -q -O - http://somewhere/image.iso \
| bfr -b 512m -p -i 100% -m 10% -t 120 -T 95% \
| growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/cdrom=/dev/fd/0
```

The buffering part is optional, but without it you will have to rely on your drive to cope with buffer underruns. That doesn't work too well if you have underruns all the time, so your Internet connection better be faster than your drive...

---

D'oh, completely missed the USB flash part. That's not burning in my book :I

```
wget -q -O - http://somewhere/image.iso > /dev/usbstick
```

or even just

```
wget -O /dev/usbstick http://somewhere/image.iso
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the device name of a CD or DVD drive to burn a CD or DVD to you can even do something like:

```
wget -O - http://somewhere/some_distro.iso | sudo dd of=/dev/sr0
```

Comment: You cannot write a DVD by directly writing to it, unlike writing a USB stick.